# Getting SPAN Text using NEXT()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following code:

```
<div>    
  <span id='1' onclick="GetValue();">Some value</span>
  <span id='2'>Some Span
     <span id='3'>Want this text</span>
  </span>
</div>

 <div>    
  <span id='1' onclick="GetValue();">Some value</span>
  <span id='2'>Some Span
     <span id='3'>Want this text</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

I need to get the text from span id=3 and this is what I have:

```
  function GetValue() {
     var get_text= $(this).next().find("#3").text();
     alert(get_text);
  }
```

Comment: First, `this` should almost never be in quotes. Secondly, why are you using traversal methods when you can select the span by id directly? `$("#3")` And finally, `this` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Sorry there were no quotes in this. I corrected it. In any case how to get the ID = 3 text?

Comment: `this` isn't what you think it is.  `this` will refer to the window object because of the way you call the function.  With an inline function such as that, you would need to pass the span element using `GetValue(this);` to be able to reference it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you can directly get the text using `id` selector like this

```
$('#myId').text();
```

Second `id` attribute's value should not be start with digit. It must be start with character and then it may followed by digit.

The issue with your code is that your `$(this)` is basically a `window` object not the `span` which trigger the click.

So you need to something like this

```
function GetValue(element) {
     var get_text= $(element).next().find("#three").text();
     alert(get_text);
}
```

with HTML

```
<span id='one' onclick="GetValue(this);">Some value</span>
  <span id='two'>Some Span
     <span id='three'>Want this text</span>
  </span>
```

**[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nKDRh/1/)**